# React.js Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do an ajax call using fetch. The database is ran through mongo and when using dummy data from a .json file, the map works correctly when decks: [], it gives the error.

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            decks: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/api/getAllDecks")
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        decks: result.decks
                    });
                    console.log("hiiii");
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                    console.log('hryyyy');
                })
    }

    render() {
        const decks = this.state.decks;
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                {this.state.decks.map(decks => (
                    <MiniCard
                        word={decks.deckName}
                    />
                ))};
            </div>
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the Fetch API, you need to transform the response into the kind of data you want in order to use it. To do that here, call `.json()` on the response object returned from the fetch call.

```
fetch('/api/getAllDecks')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true, decks: data.decks })
  })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Also, won't hurt to double check to make sure that `data.decks` is correct by doing a `console.log` on it.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I changed up the code to implement this answer and it says, Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Sounds like the response from `/api/getAllDecks` isn't actually JSON 

Comment: hmm interesting.. when i hit the route on http://localhost:3000/api/getAllDecks i am getting back JSON

Comment: If you're using create-react-app, have you proxied your API? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: I am using create-react-app and i just checked my package.json and there is not proxy set up. I will look into this! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short circut `this.state.decks`

```
 {
      this.state.decks && 
        this.state.decks.map { decks => (<MiniCard word={decks.deckName} />))
 };
```